# Wire model RC vs LC/RLGC

Tags: wire, transmission-line, passive-networks, delay

The condition for using an LC/RLGC model over an RC model is when:

f > R/(2*pi*L)

(see for example http://www.ece.tamu.edu/~spalermo/ecen689/lecture2_ee720_channels.pdf slide 19). This explains why we typically treat every normal twisted pair cable as transmission line (f>32kHz) but still use RC models for IC design (f>1.6GHz).

Why question is: WHY? How exactly is this criteria derived?

I am somewhat missing "C" in this criteria. Shouldn't it matter whether C is tiny or huge?

Comment: it does not matter how big or small C is because it will never be ignored, all the models you described have a C in them.

Comment: Hmm good point! So all that means is as soon as L (relative to R) is large enough RC is not sufficient any more?

Comment: it is not sufficient anymore because the L is large enough to change how the circuit would behave, this is very barebones, but resistances mostly change amplitude of a signal, V and I should be identical in shape for a resistor, following ohms law only the magnitude is different.

A large enough L can and will change the actual shape of a waveform in time, C does the same but since you are taking it into account in your model, it is fine.